# Line feature won't stay in place

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, line, snapping

I'm working on a storm network system and have an issue with a drain line. When I try to snap it to a point, it moves slightly to the right every time. I've checked that there isn't topography for this feature, and have tried a few different snapping options. Any ideas? ArcMap v10.3. Issue went away when I removed DWG>SHP converted files. No clue why

[image]

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: Sorry, left that out. Edited. Arcmap 10.3

Comment: The snapping is either not big enough at that scale or it is over compensating. Check your snapping to end points or vertices as well. http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/editing-fundamentals/snapping-to-a-specific-feature-while-editing.htm

Comment: I've tried both end points and vertices, and zooming out and in. I've also tried editing the vertices and it will snap to the point, but once you confirm it jumps back to the position in the picture

Comment: Make sure that the data frame's coordinate system is set to the one that the data is using.

Comment: This could be a SpatialReference problem, where the layer was defined to a coordinate resolution of 0.0001 degrees, and the coordinates are snapping to that grid as requested.